# Setting higher screen resolution

Tags: xorg, display, display-resolution

I have HP 250 G4 and I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. My screen resolution is 1366x768 now, but if I run `xrandr` it says:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      59.99*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Does that fact that it says `maximum 32767 x 32767` mean that I can set my resolution to higher value, e.g. 1920 x 1080 ? If no, why? If yes, how?

I could just try but AFAIK there's a possibility of damaging my monitor, so I would appreciate if somebody makes this things clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to your question about "maximum 32767 x 32767", but if you wanted to change the resolution or (--newmode & --addmode) doesn't work for you.

you could try the scale option,

```
xrandr --output display --scale (x)x(y).
```

**i.e**

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --scale 1.4x1.4
```

before scalling this is my xrandr output note the **Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768 part**

```
blupie@elitebook:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   1366x768      60.00*+  40.00  
   1360x768      59.96  
   1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82  
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00
```

but after I scaled my screen this is my result, note the **Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1599 x 899, maximum 32767 x 32767**

```
blupie@elitebook:~$ xrandr --output eDP1 --scale 1.17x1.17
blupie@elitebook:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1599 x 899, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1599x899+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   1366x768      60.00*+  40.00  
   1360x768      59.96  
   1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82  
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00
```

I wanted my resolution from 1366x768 to 1600x900, so 1600/1366 = 1.17, 900/768 = 1.17 which outputs to 
***--scale 1.17x1.17***

Answer (score 0):

HP 250 G4 comes with a 15,6" HD SVA 1366x768 screen.
You can use resolutions **up to 1366x768**, not higher, with the internal monitor. There's no point in using any other than the native resolution. System icons and fonts can be scaled for better viewing at higher resolutions.

The graphics chipset supports higher resolution for additional external monitor(s).